# ui-router 1.0.0 beta and nested resolves: How to rewrite

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, beta

I'm currently trying to move from ui-router 1.0.0-alpha.5 to 1.0.0.beta.3, and I don't know how to rewrite the resolve part of my states. I'm pretty sure it's relative to "9) BC-BREAK: remove support for JIT resolves." https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.1
but I'm not sure if I can keep my resolve, or if I must move all my 8 resolves to transition.onEnter.

Current code is:

```
.state('main', {
abstract: true,
url: `^${BASE_URL}?appName`,
template: '<main></main>',
resolve: {
    cms: (CmsService) => {
        return CmsService.init(); // Promise
    },
    gameDesc: (GameDescriptionService) => {
        return GameDescriptionService.init(); // Promise
    },
    cartInit: (cms, gameDesc, Cart) => {
        // Cart can't be injected before cms and gameDesc have resolved
        return Cart;
    },
    stuffWithCart: (cartInit, Cart) => {
        // Using Cart
    }
```

and Cart is like:

```
export default /*@ngInject*/ function (CmsService, GameDescriptionService) {
    class Cart {
        constructor() {
            this.cms = CmsService.getCms();
            this.gameDesc = GameDescriptionService.getDescription();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.